# C/C++ Debug Assertion Failed! (On Visual Studio Community 2015)

Tags: c++, c

I started an simple notepad C project and I am facing some problems.

I am using Virtual Studio Community 2015 with these setting:

COMPILE AS:Compile as C Code (/TC)
PREPROCESSOR DEFINITIONS:_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

char text[100000], name[120], exitkey, length, choice;
FILE *file;

printf("----------Simple Notepad----------\n\n");
printf("Enter file name:");
gets(name);
length = strlen(name);

/*File format*/
name[length] = '.';
name[length + 1] = 't';
name[length + 2] = 'x';
name[length + 3] = 't';
name[length + 4] = NULL;

/*File creation*/
if (file = fopen(name, "w+") == NULL) {
    printf("Error at opening file.\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue....");
    exitkey = _getch();
    exit(1);
}

printf("Begin\n\n------------File Start------------(MAX=100000)\n");
gets(text);
printf("\n\n----------File End----------\n");
printf("Do you want to save the file(Y/N)?");
choice =getchar();
choice = toupper(choice);

if (choice = 'Y') {
    if (fputs(text, file) == EOF) {
        printf("Error at writing file.\n");
        printf("Press any key to continue....");
        exitkey = _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fclose(file) == EOF) {
        printf("Error at closing file.\n");
        printf("Press any key to continue....");
        exitkey = _getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File has been saved.");
}
else if (choice = 'N') printf("File has been not saved.");

printf("Press any key to continue...");
exitkey = _getch();
exit(1);

return 0;
```

}

The program works fine till the save file option.
When is select yes or no I get this window.

[image]

If anyone knows how can I solve this pleae help.
Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the above comment, this `if (file = fopen(name, "w+") == NULL)` needs to be changed to `if ((file = fopen(name, "w+")) == NULL)`. Note the extra parentheses. Also, you have a perfectly good debugger there - suggest you use it more than you currently seem to be to help you find your bugs.

Comment: When I see this dialog (Debug Assertion Failed!) I hit retry and then go up the callstack to the line of my code that caused the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says you are passing `nullptr` as the stream pointer (file pointer). It's true because

```
if (file = fopen(name, "w+") == NULL) {
  ...
}
```

assigns `0` to `file`.

`==` (comparison) operator has higher precedence than `=` (assignment). So the return value of `fopen()` is compared with `NULL` which is false (because `fopen()` was success). The result of the comparison is `0` which is assigned to `file`.

It should be

```
if ( (file = fopen(name, "w+")) == NULL) {
  ...
}
```

---

I personally prefer writing such calls on a separate line and avoid assignments within an if statement. I would write it as:

```
file = fopen(name, "w+");

if (fp == NULL) {
  ...
}
```